# Верстка под ретину -- как определять плотность пикселя?

Tags: html, css, mobile, retina

*Это вопрос из прошлого и поставлен он был несколько странно. Но ответ ниже более чем актуален.*

---

Перелопатив с десяток статей я начал осознавать, что `ppi` - большая палка в колеса. Как с ним бороться, пока не ясно.

**Итак, у нас есть элементарная страница:** [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/AHzYJ/1/)

Мы хотим `14px` (к примеру) - как основной размер шрифта. Допустим, что так было в `PSD` от дизайнера. От этого будем отталкиваться.

Обварачиваем весь контент в `div.font-size-setting`, которому выставляем `font-size: 1.4em` (так как после нормализации у нас было `10px`).

**Смотрим на страницу с разных устройств:**

[image]

Будь там iphone4 шрифт и квадратик были бы еще меньше. Проблема, очевидно, в большой разнице в `ppi` (`pixels per inch`) устройств. Обычные мониторы имеют `96ppi`. У iphone3 `163ppi`. У виты `220ppi`.

**Очевидное решение** - это определить `ppi` устройства и увеличить шрифт. С последним проблем никаких. Обарачиваем в `div.font-size-normalize` и в зависимости от `dpi` выставляем соответствующий шрифт: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/AHzYJ/2/)

Получаем:

**`div.font-size-setting`** - чтобы выставить размер шрифта от дизайнера,

**`div.font-size-normalize`** - делаем этот шрифт одинакового размера (визуально) на всех устройствах.

[image]

Яблофон чуть растянул сам шрифт или увеличил расстояниями между строчкам, но по сути все сходится. Так или иначе, квадратик с размерами в `em` везде одинаковый, хоть линейкой меряй.

**Вопрос в том, как определять `ppi`?**

1.**`media queries - resolution`**
Медиа запросы умеют определять не только ширину и высоту, но и много других характеристик, в том числе и `dpi` (`dots per inch`). Вообще `dpi` - бессмысленный параметр для дисплея, так как это параметр для печати принтером, но в нашем случае совпадает с `ppi`.

Я решил, что не плохо было бы сделать шаг в `0.1em`. Это примерно каждые `10ppi`. Взяв наши `96ppi` за `1em` составил [табличку](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22619948/i_dpi_normalize.xlsx) и посчитал диапазон так, чтобы интересующие нас  значения были в середине. Составил запросы:

```
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 90dpi) and (max-resolution: 100dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 1em; /* normal desktops */ }
    }
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 101dpi) and (max-resolution: 111dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 1.1em; }
    }
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 112dpi) and (max-resolution: 122dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 1.2em; }
    }
  /*...*/
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 158dpi) and (max-resolution: 168dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 1.7em; /* iphone3 */ }
    }
  /*...*/
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 216dpi) and (max-resolution: 226dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 2.3em; /* ps vita */ }
    }
  /*...*/
    @media screen and (min-resolution: 322dpi) and (max-resolution: 332dpi)  {
        .font-size-normalize { font-size: 3.4em; /* iphone4 */ }
    }
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/AHzYJ/3/](http://jsfiddle.net)

Последние версии десктопных браузеров проработали медиазапросы. Браузеры iphone3 и ps vita не осилили. Думаю последние яблофоны, яблопэды, дройдофоны все же справятся, но тем не менее решение далеко не пуленепробиваемо :(

2.**media queries - devicePixelRatio и канонический пиксель**
`dip - density(device)-independent pixel` - что то вроде канонического пикселя. Равен одному физическому пикселю на `160ppi`. С другой стороны мы имеем параметр `devicePixelRatio`, который может быть использован как аргумент медиа-запроса относительно канонического пикселя:

```
@media screen and (device-pixel-ratio: 1) {}
```

Можно написать аналогичное примеру выше множество запросов:

```
@media screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1) {
    .font-size-normalize { font-size: 2.3em; /* ps vita */ }
}
```

Но у меня ни для одного девайса/компьютера/браузера этого толком сделать не получилось. Такое ощущение, что этот параметр может быть только целочисленным: единица - для `iphone3`, двойка - для `iphone4`. Более того, требуются вендерные префиксы, что уже как минимум говорит об отсутвии кросс-браузерности или кросс-девайсности. Еще одна несостыковка в том, что "`device-pixel-ratio: 2`" (означающий `320ppi`) отрабатывает на `iphone4`, обладающий `326ppi`.

3.`JS`

```
alert(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

Думаю, оно работает точно так же как и второй способ. На `iphone3` я увидел "1", так же как в десктопном браузере и на вите, что само собой чушь. На `iphone4` высветилось "2", но после предыдущих фэйлов это уже не имеет значение. Еще проблема: тормозилла не справилась и показала `undefined`.

4.Самописные `JS`-функции, определяющие `ppi`.
Что-то типа взять `device-width` и поделить на `width`. Это работает на мобильных устройствах, так как нельзя сплющить окно браузера, но в десктопном браузере мы можем просто уменьшить размер окна и все сломается.

В конечном итоге, я не нашел ни одного полнофункционального решения. Думаю, что просто должно пройти время, пока "`device-pixel-ratio: n`" будет пониматься всеми. А пока надо придумать как максимизировать количество удачных определений `ppi`. Ведь описанные выше способы частично, но все же работают.

Кто что думает по этому поводу, какие можетe предложить решения и как можно обобщить вышеуказанные способы в один пусть полурабочий вариант?

Comment: А каков итоговый смысл операций? Ведь на мобильных устройствах для этих целей зум используется. одно дело чтоб текст читаемый был при изначальном зуме, другое дело чтоб вся страница влезла на экран - пяти айфонов не хватит, чтоб отобразить скажем яндекс.ру с мониторным ппи. потому ведь и разделяют мобильную версию сайта и обычную, что не только разный шрифт используется, но и вообще верстка другая. кстати, картинки вы будете масштабировать таким же образом?

Comment: По сути, это примочка для адапивной верстки в привочном смылсе (по Итану Маркоту, в зависимости от ширины). Зум там не уместен, так как тогда адаптивная верстка и не нужна вовсе. Хочется разрабатывать так, чтобы пользователю вообще не хотелось зумировать.

Про остальные элементы да, во первых адаптивная верстка, во вторых зависимость от ppi. Для умной, такой, верстки нужно всегда держать под рукой параметр - какой-то коэффициент, на который будут перемножаться все размеры. Можно было бы завести SASS-переменную, например, но у нас и так есть родной естественный коэффициен - размер шрифта.

Comment: Строчка #logo { width: 8.714285714285714em; } может показаться дикостью на первый взгляд. Но почему бы и нет? Дизайнер нарисовал лого в 122px при 14px шрифте. Мы перевели 122px в em и установили такой размер. Пользователи десктопников увидят логотип в 122px. Пользователи iphone3 увидят логотип в 207px, так как коэффициент для них это 1.7em, но фищически он будет таких же размеров. Аналогично квадратику в моем первом примере.

Тут, конечно, есть и другие проблемы: это может быть слегка расточительно, отнять у пользователь iphone3 207px на логотип, но это решается медиа запросами от ширины.

Comment: Идею понял, не понял практическое применение. Вот яндекс, например, вместо зума у вас будет скроллинг в лучшем случае вертикальный (при плавующей верстке), а то и горизонтальный еще в придачу. но логотипы кроме того, что не поместятся по ширине айфона будут видимо еще и масштабированы без сглаживания. Если взять, например, приложения под андроид, то там под каждое ppi делают свои ресурсы - и картинки, и разметка... SASS переменные выглядят кстати говоря более системным подходом.

Comment: Поверстав несколько дней начал сомневать в такой сильной зависимости от em. Постоянно упираюсь в то, что нет никакой связи с шириной. Что касается основной массы графических элементов и блоков тут да, либо проценты и резина (обычная или в диапазонах разрешений) или пиксели и больше медиа-запросов. Думая над вашими словами утихомирил пыл :)

Такой подходит работает хорошо, когда нет зависимости от ширины. Например, когда верстаем мобильную версию или используем HTML5-фреймворк типа sencha touch для мобильных приложений.

Comment: Однако, проблема остается. Текст и элементы зависящие от размера шрифта (напримемер маджины параграфов и заголовков, пэддинги списков) и, конечно, сам размер шрифта хочется задавать в em. На той же несчастной вите дефолтовые 14px по прежнему нечитабельны пока не прозумируешь. Плюс ко всему, есть свойства, типа border-width, которые не проглатывают проценты. Хотелось бы сюда добавить хоть какой-то относительности.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Спустя какое-то время я пришел к тому, что надо работать по второму предложенному мною способу. Суть рабты примерно следующая. Сайт верстается "как обычно", все размеры задаются в пикселях. Только теперь width: 100px не означает ширину в 100 физических пикселей дисплея. Это 100 некоторых абстрахных пикселей (device independent pixel). А дальше операционная система (или браузер) уже сами решают, как показать один такой абстрактный пиксель на дисплее. Помогает им в этом параметр devicePixelRatio. Если этот параметр равен единице, то абстрактный пиксель показывается один в один с физическим пикселем. Если равен двойке, то используется квадрат из четырех пикселей.

Если мы возьмем случайный сайт, вообще не оптимизированный под дисплеи с высокой плотностью пикселя, то он никак не сожмется на ретине. Он будет выгялдеть как на обычном дисплее.

Получается, что за размерами следить не нужно. Ширины, высоты, бордюры, тени и прочее можно задавать в обычных пикселях. И не беспокоится о том, что же там будет на ретине. А вот над графикой придется попотеть. Картинки на девайсах с высокой плостностью пикселя  выглядят растянутыми. Их надо заменять на картинки увеличенные в соответствующее количество раз. Например.

```
div {
    background: url(cake.png) no-repeat center top;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       screen and (   -moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    div {
        background-image: url(cake@2x.png);
        background-size: 100%; // или вариации
    }
}
```

Comment: Современный синтаксис запроса на плотность пикселя: `@media (min-resolution: 2dppx)`.