# Область просмотра браузера android

Tags: javascript, android, css, webbrowser

Разрешение экрана моего смартфона - 480х854. Открываю какую-нибудь страницу. Запрашиваю размеры просмотра в любом браузере (с помощью javascript: alert(screen.width или screen.height)) и выдает 320 и 570 соответственно.

Вопрос: почему область просмотра "урезана"? Как достичь того, чтобы браузер адекватно оценивал границы отображения. Из-за этого неправильно реагируют медиазапросы в CSS.

Comment: какой именно это браузер?

Comment: @metalurgus стандартный и chrome. В firefox-е не могу проверить - javascript из адресной строки не поддерживается

Comment: а pixel ratio у Вас какое?

Comment: @OlmerDale 1,5. Вот тут и кроется загадка :) спасибо большое!

Comment: Здесь ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/134456/Верстка-с-учетом-ppi-устройств-как-определять-каков-подход